# Como puedo obtener los resultados una consulta a partir de una variable table

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedure, plsql, subconsultas

Quisiera saber puedo obtener los resultados de una consulta a partir de datos almacenados en una variable tipo table.
Actualmente tengo estas tres tablas y quiero sacar el nombre los participantes según el idAssessment 24

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto cree una variable tipo tabla que me guarda los idParticpante relacionado entre estas tres tablas y a partir de estos datos en la tabla obtener los nombre pero no me trae datos.
Actualmente mi script es el siguiente:

DECLARE @valoresParticipantesId table(idParticipante int)
DECLARE @idAssessment int
set @idAssessment = 24
select DISTINCT RP.idParticipante from RutinaParticipantes RP where idRutina in (SELECT idMGRutina FROM MGRutina  WHERE idAssessment = @idAssessment)
select P.nombre, P.horasTrabajadas, P.nivelJerarquico from MGParticipante P ,@valoresParticipantesId VP WHERE P.idMGParticipante = VP.idParticipante

El resultado que me arroja es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La sintaxis que muestra NO es de Oracle PL/SQL, elimine la etiqueta "plsql"

Answer (score 0):

No haces el insert en la variable de tabla

```
DECLARE @valoresparticipantesid table(idParticipante INT);

DECLARE @idassessment INT;

set @idassessment = 24;
INSERT INTO @valoresparticipantesid
select DISTINCT 
       RP.idParticipante
       from RutinaParticipantes RP
       where idRutina in
        (
            SELECT idMGRutina
                   FROM Rutina
                   WHERE idAssessment = @idassessment
        );

select P.nombre
     , P.horasTrabajadas
     , P.nivelJerarquico
       from MGParticipante P
          , @valoresparticipantesid VP 
          ON P.idMGParticipante = VP.idParticipante;
```

Mejor utilizar la sintaxis para las relaciones en ON que en Where.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo a la perfección.